# HTML select dropdown countries and states using (countries.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently working HTML dropdown countries and states with the code. I am geeting list of countries and states working fine. when User select the United Arab Emirates my Label of State should change to Emirates dynamically. For example if I select **Swizerland** the label of state should change to **Canton**. How to change?

```
Countries--Hong kong -- Area Code -- state label name
Countries--Switzerland -- Canton -- State label name
```

Here is the menu format:

I have created one more array in script files for the label which will change dynamically

```
var label_arr = new Array("Prefucture","Emirate","UF","Area Code","Canton","Country","Province");
```

Here is the current code for populating states:

```
function populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId) {

var selectedCountryIndex =document.getElementById(countryElementId).selectedIndex;
alert("welcome to state" + selectedCountryIndex.value);

var stateElement = document.getElementById(stateElementId);

stateElement.length = 0;
stateElement.options[0] = new Option('Select State', '');
stateElement.selectedIndex = 0;

var state_arr = s_a[selectedCountryIndex].split("|");

for (var i = 0; i < state_arr.length; i++) {
    stateElement.options[stateElement.length] = new Option(state_arr[i], state_arr[i]);
}

}



 function populateCountries(countryElementId, stateElementId) {
// given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts     <option> tags
var countryElement = document.getElementById(countryElementId);
countryElement.length = 0;
countryElement.options[0] = new Option('Select Country', '');
countryElement.selectedIndex = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < country_arr.length; i++) {
    countryElement.options[countryElement.length] = new Option(country_arr[i], country_arr[i]);
}

// Assigned all countries. Now assign event listener for the states.

if (stateElementId) {
    countryElement.onchange = function () {
        populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId);
    };
   }
  }
```

Here is the jQuery code:

```
  $(document).ready(function (){
$("#country").on('change', function(){
  if( $('#country').val() == "United Arab Emirates" ){

    $('.dynamic_state').text("Emirates");
  }else{

    $('.dynamic_state').text("States");
  } 
});
});
```

This was working fine when the user select only United Arab Emirates.

Here is the [jsbin link](http://jsbin.com/qaqiqi/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Which part of the code here changes the label to 'Canton'?

Comment: @halfer sorry I have not tried in this code I am confused how to dynamically add this

Comment: Well, inside your `countryElement.onchange` is where your country changes, so I think it would go there. Get the label element and change the text contents. You'll need to read a label name from an array structure - do you have that data available?

Comment: i found the solution for the  first query but not for second please help me

document.getElementById("country").value = "United Arab Emirates"; by default I am getting the UAE as the selected value now

Comment: Yes here are they

Japan - Prefucture


United arab - Emirate

Brazil - UF

Hong kong - Area Code

Switzerland - Canton

GBR - country

Chnina, canada, Spain, Italy,Poland - Province+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is rather broad, so I'll offer some clues for your research. Here is the code where you handle a country change in your menu:

```
if (stateElementId) {
  countryElement.onchange = function () {
    populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId);
  };
}
```

The first thing to do is to ensure your event works. Change the above to this:

```
if (stateElementId) {
  countryElement.onchange = function () {
    alert('Changed country');
    populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId);
  };
}
```

My guess is the `if()` clause is wrong - the event should be attached in all cases, not just when a selected state is provided. But this is up to you to test - make sure that the `alert()` triggers in all cases when it should.

Next, you need to set up some way of reading the label that each country gives to its internal divisions. You're using a global array `country_arr` for the countries, so perhaps set `label_arr` or similar, with each position containing "Canton", "State", "Department", "Region" as appropriate. You have not shown where this array is set up, so just set up the new array in the same place.

You can then add the appropriate code to change the label inside this event handler.

Please give this a go, and let me know how you get on. I would recommend you clean up the code indentation too, as it will make it easier to work with.

Comment: Hi @halfter i tried please help me still not coming http://jsbin.com/qaqiqi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Mahadevan, what are you stuck on in particular? Break the problem down into manageable chunks. Did you set up the global array? Have you been able to reset the label caption? Does the change event fire when you want to? (Four questions, please answer them all fully).

Comment: yes the event got fired 

then i have tired added new array for the label

Comment: first I am looking for dynamic label change

Comment: how to map the new array with value from the drop down any idea please

Comment: I have updated the question I want only one dynamically label change kindly please help me

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution

```
             $("#country").on('change', function(){
            if( $('#country').val() == "United Arab Emirates" ){                   
                $('.dynamic_state').text("Emirates");
            }else if( $('#country').val() == "Japan" ){
                $('.dynamic_state').text("Prefucture");
            }else{
                $('.dynamic_state').text("States");
            } 
        });
```

thanks for the people who supports me here.

Comment: Pleased you have solved it! I think 'Prefucture' should be spelled 'Prefecture'. Do you need one for Canton as well, for Switzerland?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-off example of how I used jQuery to dynamically populate State and County drop boxes -- County was dependent on State. I started with a pandas dataframe which gets converted to JSON in the HTML below.

HTML:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="State">State:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="State" name="State">
        <option disabled selected> -- Select a State -- </option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="County">County:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="County" name="County" disabled>
        <option selected> -- Select a County -- </option>
    </select>
</div>

<script>
    var state_county = {{ df.to_dict(orient='records') | tojson | safe }};
</script>
```

JS:

```
function extract_property(prop) {
    //Takes JSON
    //Returns array of prop where prop is 'State' or 'County'
    return function (e) {
        return e[prop]
    }
}

function populate_select(selector, list) {
    //take a select box name ('selector') and a list ('list')
    //append select option to 'selector' for each item in list
    var element = $(selector);
    // clear the select but leave ' -- Please select -- '
    element.html("<option disabled selected> -- Please select -- </option>");
    list.forEach(function (item) {
        element.append(
            $('<option>', {value: item}).text(item)
        );
    })
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    var states = $.unique(state_county.map(extract_property('State')));
    populate_select('#State', states);

    $("#State").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() != "") {
            $("#County").removeAttr("disabled")
        }

        var state = $("#State").find("option:selected").text();
        var county = state_county.filter(function (e) {
            return e["State"] == state
        });
        var counties = $.unique(county.map(extract_property('County')));
        console.log(counties);
        populate_select('#County', counties);

    });
});
```